# Enviar email con Ionic 1

Tags: ionic

Tengo una app ionic 1 que envía un email, levanta el cliente del dispositivo móvil y lo envía. Funciona perfecto, pero el origen es la cuenta de correo del gmail por ejemplo, según tengo configurado en el móvil.

Quiero cambiar eso, y poner en el campo "De: ", origen, una cuenta de correo que traigo en una variable. Es esto posible ? Les agradeceré me ayuden, muchas gracias!

Comment: Esa acción tendrias que realizarla en tu backend. y buscar como hacerlo con el lenguaje que uses.

Comment: Gracias por responder, no es un email automático, es un email que el usuario escribe sobre el cliente de mail del móvil, solo con href desde la app que abre cliente. No utiliza, php en este caso, ya que no utilizo el backend.

Answer (score 0):

Yo probaria utilizando la Api Native de Ionic que esta orientada a los Emails.[Haz click aqui para verla](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer/).
En ionic no te recomiendo utilizar el href, ya que cuenta con pocas opciones.
Ademas la documentacion de Ionic es muy buena, te recomiendo chequearla.
Y actualizate a IONIC 3.
Espero te ayude